# Can't take control of USB drive on VMware

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, usb-flash-drive, vmware-workstation

I’m running VMWare Workstation on Windows 7 x86-64, and a Mac OS X 10.8 install inside the VM. Whenever I try to connect my USB drive to the Mac OS X 10.8 guest, it just doesn't gets recognized. The USB drive works on the host, but not on guest. I’ve already tried restarting, changing ports and all but nothing works. Can I get help, please?

Comment: What is the USB formatted as?

Comment: @bungeshea NTFS. It won't even show up in the "Removable Devices" list.

Comment: this is why some people simply jump into *BootCamp*. Make sure the pendrive is not already mounted (automatically, probably) in OSX. also, are you sure you have ntfs support?

Comment: @Znau the fact is, it won't even *connect* to the guest, so it isn't appearing even on disk utility. it's not showing up in the list of devices i can connect.

Comment: @wingleader part 2 of my comment: are you sure you have ntfs support?

Comment: @Znau where, in OSX? Yep, i do, and even though, the device won't *reach* osx at all, because vmware won't connect it.

Comment: have you tried to connect the same drive to another computer? does it work?

Comment: Yes. It works on the host too.

Comment: @wingleader i'll add a possible answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this solves your problem

in the execute prompt type:

```
diskmgmt.msc
```

then, select the usb drive and change its letter to one not in use in the system.
close the utility, and check if the drive now displays correctly. if not, unplug and re-plug it in.

NOTE: this answer is obsolete since new data reached me through the question owner. will update this answer when (if or not) the problem is solved.

Comment: Uh, am i supposed to do that on the host? Why? There's no letter conflict happening here ._.

Comment: 100% your problem matches drive letter issue symptoms. give it a try, no harm comes out of it.

Comment: Okay, i'l try it and report back in a few hours( or days >_< )

Comment: if you dont want to be helped, dont post a question. your host is probably having drive letter assignment problems, caused to an already in use drive letter being attempted to be assigned to a new drive(your usb drive). if the drive isnt detected by the OS hosting the VM, the VM itself wont detect it.

Comment: Dude, the drive *IS* detected by the OS hosting! It's just VMware that is bugging around this... Also, i do want to be helped, but you don't always have your files when you want, where you want.

Comment: @wingleader "Dude" then please make it clear the USB *IS* recognized by the host system. i was totally confused by that fact, then assumed it wasn't recognized at all. please try this guide: http://ericwijaya.wordpress.com/2010/03/12/vmware-usb-cannot-connect-to-host-usb/

Comment: Sorry, i though i made it clear *a lot* of times, but now that i'm reading again, that's not really true T_T. I have an Intel USB 3.0 driver so i'l check it out. Really thanks.